# Store spinner data in SQLite database and display it in another activity

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-spinner

In my main activity, my `EditText` named `date` gets a `NullPointerException`.
This is my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        Spinner menuList;
        EditText menu;
        EditText date;
        EditText time;
        CheckBox dailyAlarm;
        CheckBox reminder;

        String item;
        String setTime;
        String setDate;
        String menuDetails;
        String spItem;

        private int mYear,mMonth,mDay,mHour,mMinute;

        ArrayList<String> a= new ArrayList<String>();

        String[] from = {DBHelper.COLUMN_DATE,DBHelper.COLUMN_TIME,DBHelper.COLUMN_MENU};
        int[] to = {R.id.spList,R.id.date,R.id.time,R.id.menu};
        private ListView listView;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
            time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);


            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            menuList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.menuList);
            //spItem = menuList.getSelectedItem().toString();
            menu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.menuET);
            DBHelper2 helper2 = new DBHelper2(this);
            menuDetails = menu.getText().toString();

            helper2.insert(setDate,setTime,menuDetails);
            a = (ArrayList<String>) helper2.getAllInfo();
           /* ArrayAdapter adp = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,a);
            listView.setAdapter(adp);
    */
            //ArrayList<String> getInfo = (ArrayList<String>) helper2.getAllInfo();
            //SimpleAdapter info = new SimpleAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_show_result,getInfo,from,to,0);



        DBSpinner dbSpinner = new DBSpinner(this);
        dbSpinner.insert("Breakfast");
        dbSpinner.insert("Lunch");
        dbSpinner.insert("Dinner");

        ArrayList<String> list = dbSpinner.getAll();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner,R.id.spinnerID,list);
        menuList.setAdapter(adapter);

        menuList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


        date.setOnClickListener(this);
        time.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        if (v == date){
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    date.setText(dayOfMonth +"-"+(monthOfYear+1)+"-"+year);



                }
            },mYear, mMonth,mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
            setDate = date.getText().toString();
        }
        else if (v == time){
            final  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    time.setText(hourOfDay +" : "+minute);
                }
            },mHour,mMinute,false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
            setTime = time.getText().toString();
        }

    }
    public void save(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowResult.class);
        intent.putExtra("menuList",item);
        intent.putExtra("menu",menuDetails);
        intent.putExtra("date",setDate);
        intent.putExtra("time",setTime);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is my second activity, which should show the result in a `TextView`. It does not:

```
 public class ShowResult extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView menulist;
    TextView menu;
    TextView date;
    TextView time;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_result);

        menulist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spList);
        menu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menu);
        date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

        Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();

            String menuListS = intent.getString("menuList");
            String menuS = intent.getString("menu");
            String dateS = intent.getString("date");
            String timeS = intent.getString("time");


            menulist.setText(menuListS);
            menu.setText(menuS);
            date.setText(dateS);
            time.setText(timeS);



    }
}
```

To store my `Spinner` data within an `SQLiteDatabase`, I do the following:

```
    public class DBSpinner extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "spinner.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "spinner";

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NULL UNIQUE )";




    public DBSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insert(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        ContentValues values;
        try{
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("name",name);
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAll(){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try{
            String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME;
            Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery(query,null);
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                    list.add(name);
                }
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
        }
        return list;

    }

}
```

To store the other data within an `SQLiteDatabase`, I do as follows:

```
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "diet.db";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "diet";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_SPINNER_ITEM = "item";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";
    public static final String COLUMN_MENU = "menu";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( "+ COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "+
            COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT , "+COLUMN_MENU +" TEXT , " + COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT  ) ";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

    public class DBHelper2 {
    private DBHelper dbHelper;


    public DBHelper2(Context context){
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    public void Delete(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,null);
        db.close();
    }

    public int insert(String date,String time,String menu){
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_DATE,date);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_TIME,time);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_MENU,menu);

        long insert = db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();
        return (int) insert;
    }

    public List<String> getAllInfo(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ DBHelper.TABLE_NAME;
        List<String> allInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        String datepicker;
        String timepicker;
        String menu;

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                datepicker = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_DATE));
                timepicker = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_TIME));
                menu = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_MENU));

                allInfo.add(datepicker);
                allInfo.add(timepicker);
                allInfo.add(menu);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        return allInfo;
    }

}
```

I am new to Android. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you verify that your `activity_main` layout has the right EditText with its id `datePicker`?